# Separate regression lines overlaid in ggplot2

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, plot, tidyverse

I'm trying to replicate the plot I'm showing below without success. The thick red regression lines should come from the `int3` data.frame. The thin grey regression lines should come from `int2` data.frame.

Is there a fix to achieve my desired plot?

```
library(lme4)
library(tidyverse)

dd <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/e/master/3.csv')

m31 <- lmer(math~year+(1|schoolid/childid), data = dd)

co <- coef(m31)

int2 = co$`childid:schoolid`
int2$ch_id <- substr(rownames(int2), 11, 14)
  
int3 = co$schoolid
int3$sch_id <- rownames(int3)


ggplot(data = dd, aes(x = year, y = math, group = factor(childid)))+ geom_point()+ facet_wrap(~schoolid)+
geom_abline(data = int2, aes(intercept=`(Intercept)`, slope=year)) +  
  geom_abline(data = int3, aes(intercept=`(Intercept)`, slope=year), color=2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add columns corresponding to the `group` variable and the faceting variable to the data frames `int2` and `int3` so that the regression lines will only appear on the appropriate panel and will be split appropriately by group.

It looks like this was partially done in your example, but incorrectly because the ID columns were given different names. They should have the same names as the variables in `dd`.

```
int2 = co$`childid:schoolid`
int2$childid <- substr(rownames(int2), 1, 9)
int2$schoolid <- substr(rownames(int2), 11, 14)

int3 = co$schoolid
int3$schoolid <- rownames(int3)


ggplot(data = dd, aes(x = year, y = math, group = factor(childid)))+ geom_point()+ facet_wrap(~schoolid)+
  geom_abline(data = int2, aes(intercept=`(Intercept)`, slope=year)) +  
  geom_abline(data = int3, aes(intercept=`(Intercept)`, slope=year), color=2)
```

[image]

So far so good. But it looks like in your example plot the regression lines have the same range of x-values as the data. To fix that, you would need to replace `geom_abline` with `geom_segment`. I calculated the range of x values needed for each `schoolid` and `childid`, and found the endpoints of the segments that way.

```
# Calculate range of values for schoolid and childid.
year_range_by_schoolid <- dd %>% group_by(schoolid) %>% summarize(min_year = min(year), max_year = max(year))
year_range_by_childid <- dd %>% group_by(schoolid, childid) %>% summarize(min_year = min(year), max_year = max(year))

# Find min and max points for each line.
int2 <- int2 %>% 
  mutate(schoolid = as.integer(schoolid),
         childid = as.integer(childid)) %>%
  left_join(year_range_by_childid) %>%
  mutate(min_y = `(Intercept)` + year * min_year,
         max_y = `(Intercept)` + year * max_year)

int3 <- int3 %>% 
  mutate(schoolid = as.integer(schoolid)) %>%
  left_join(year_range_by_schoolid) %>%
  mutate(min_y = `(Intercept)` + year * min_year,
         max_y = `(Intercept)` + year * max_year)


ggplot(data = dd, aes(x = year, y = math, group = factor(childid)))+ geom_point()+ facet_wrap(~schoolid)+
  geom_segment(data = int2, aes(x = min_year, y = min_y, xend = max_year, yend = max_y)) +  
  geom_segment(data = int3, aes(x = min_year, y = min_y, xend = max_year, yend = max_y, group = factor(schoolid)), color=2)
```

[image]